Probability that bingo cards are disjoint
In Mark Bollman's Basic Gambling Mathematics, page 90:
Exercise 2.22. Two bingo cards with different sets of 24 numbers are called disjoint; cards with one or more numbers in common are said to overlap. (The rest is irrelevant and omitted.) (The definition is a little strange. My interpretation is that two disjoint cards have no common numbers hence 48 distinct numbers in them.)
Exercise 2.23. Find the probability that two randomly selected bingo cards will have no numbers in common.
Exercise 2.24. ... Use the probability calculated in 2.23 to find the probability that a package of 3000 cards will contain two or more disjoint cards.
The book gives answer $0.0353$ to Ex 2.24 but no answer to Ex 2.23. My calculation for Ex 2.23 is
\begin{equation*}
p=\left(\frac{\binom{10}{5}}{\binom{15}{5}}\right)^4\cdot \frac{\binom{11}{4}}{\binom{15}{4}}\approx 1.1988\times 10^{-5}.
\end{equation*}
Now my question is how to find the probability in Ex 2.24. Equivalently, we can calculate the probability that no two cards are disjoint; then take one minus that. Note that two bingo cards being disjoint is not independent; there can be at most three mutually disjoint bingo cards.
Can you help? Thanks!
Note. A bingo card consists of five columns. The five numbers in the first column are from $1$ to $15$; then $5$, $4$, $5$, $5$ numbers from $16$ to $30$, $31$ to $45$, $46$ to $60$ and $61$ to $75$, respectively. No number can be repeated. The figure shows a bingo card.


I don't see how we can answer this without knowing how the numbers are selected.  I'm guessing that they are chosen uniformly at random from some pre-set range.  That is, there is some number $N$ and, from the integers between $1$ and $N$, we choose $24$ and each of the $\binom N{24}$ selections is equally likely.  Is that correct?  If so, what is $N$?

And, if that is correct, how are the cards in a package selected?  Presumably not "independently" as (I'm guessing) duplicates would be blocked.  Or is it simply that duplicates have such low probability that it's safe to ignore them?  Though I'd think it was a problem if two cards both yielded a Bingo with the same selection of $5$ numbers.  Is that blocked?

@lulu For each bingo card, the numbers are chosen uniformly at random as follows. The first column consists of 5 numbers from 1-15; the second column 5 numbers from 16-30; then 4 numbers from 31-45 and 5, 5 from 46-60, 61-75.

For your second question, I guess the package is selected at random. There are $\binom{3000}{2}$ pairs. But being disjoint is independent and thus it is incorrect to take $(1-p)^{(3000\cdot 2999)/2}$.

@lulu In case you were wondering, the numbers in a single column of a bingo card are always distinct.

@RobertShore  thanks!   I think I knew that, though I had no idea that the columns were segregated by size.  Been a while since I played.

@HaoranChen  Thanks!  Maybe I'm wrong, but I doubt that those rules are universally known.  Maybe it helps to add them to your post.  I agree that the low probability of matched Bingo probably makes it safe to ignore that risk (though I bet it happens).

As to question $2.24$  ...  Perhaps I still don't understand the rules, but isn't it obvious that the answer is $0$?   Forget the whole card, just look at the first column.  Best you could manage is three disjoint cards.  If you have four, there will definitely be an overlap in the first column.  Of course, it is different if "overlap" requires the duplicate numbers to be in the same position, but is that the case?

No. The probability is not 0. Imagine cards A and B are disjoint, i.e. they have 48 all different numbers; card A and the other 2998 cards all have a common number 1. This satisfies the problem condition and has positive probability.

Note that $1-(1-p)^{2999}\approx 0.0353$, so the book's answer is the probability that the first card is disjoint from at least one other card.

@DanielMathias Thank you so much. So, I guess the question is not stated correctly.
